# Необходимо синонимизировать [искусственный-интеллект]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На сайте есть две метки

- [искусственный-интеллект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) (111 вопрос)
- [ai](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ai) (49 вопросов)

(у обеих есть описание). Надо бы их синонимизировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 54 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 49 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 41 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'ai': [ai] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 152
tag remapping of [искусственный-интеллект] and [ai] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
10 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym ai -> искусственный-интеллект was approved!
```